# Roasting large leg of wild boar

Tags: temperature, pork, roast

I have a very large joint of wild boar that I'm intending to roast, but none of the recipes I can find have in mind the size of joint I'm about to cook and I'm very worried I'll undercook it.

I want to slow cook it in a (electric) oven; it's a leg joint of ~ 6.7 kg/14.8 lbs.

How long and at what temperature should I cook this?

Comment: There's some guidance on this here - http://www.brokenarrowranch.com/Recipes/Tips-WholeLegs.htm

Comment: What temperature are you planning to use to cook the leg?

Comment: Use a thermometer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a recipe I was comfortable online with as none of them seemed to be able to take into account a hunk of meat that size.

In the end I cooked it for 220 C for 30 mins and then 170 C for 6 1/2 hours, rebasting it every hour with the overflow juices and straining off the (copious amount of) excess fat so it didn't deep fry itself.

Result? Delicious

Comment: Generally speaking, time per mass is a poor way to go about roasting any meat anyway. Invest (any by invest I mean a tenner) in a digital probe thermometer and cook it to its safe temperature, and you take out all the guess work.